# Is there any way to get two different languages' kernels run on the same Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, matlab, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am creating a course for switching from Matlab to Python, and it would be great if I could have a (series of) Jupyter notebook(s) that run both Python and Matlab code. I successfully managed to create notebooks running Matlab code, however, is there any way to have two kernels running on the same notebook, one for Python and one for Matlab?

Comment: [Script of Scripts (SoS) is a computational environment for the development and execution of scripts in multiple languages for daily computational research.](https://vatlab.github.io/sos-docs/), but not in Jupyter.

Comment: Thanks @Trenton_M, it seems they integrate with Jupyter notebooks quite easily, so I'm giving this a try.